# rails has_many gives 'undefined method' / destroy does not delete foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I have a little issue with has_many and I don't get where I'm wrong and searching through here didn't give me an answer yet.

I am writing a litte application to manage parties. Therefore a have a model Person for the people helping at the party

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
end
```

an a model Section to manage the different places (a shotbar, a place to get food, etc)

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :shifts
end
```

The routes I used are simply(they work)

```
resources :people
resources :sections
```

My migrations are as follows

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :people do |t|
  t.string :vname
  t.string :nname
  t.string :mail

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

and

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :sections do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.text :text
  t.integer :person_id

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

The Problem I have is: as I understand has_many I should now be able to use

```
@stuff=Person.sections
```

to get all sections where a certain person is working.

Yet, this gives me "undefined method `sections' for #". The Problem actually occured when I destroyed a person and the foreign keys in the section object remained whereas I thought rails would set them to NULL, e.g.

```
@person=Person.find(8)
@person.destroy
```

ended up somewhere in

```
couldn't find person with id=8
```

while getting the show action of section

```
def show
  @section=Section.find(params[:id])
  if @section.person_id
    @person=Person.find(@section.person_id)
  end
end
```

I don't know what to do or if I'm missing some migrations. Rails does not seem to acknowledge this 1 to many relation. I already checked the documentation and stuff but can't find the difference. Perhaps you can help.

Thanks alot, sven

Comment: `sections` method is defined for `Person` instance, not class.

Comment: Thanks! that solved the first problem... but why do the foreign keys remain after I destroy a certain person? What I hope for is that when I delete a person from the system each sections person_id ,where this person was working, is set to NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add dependence rule, eg:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
  ...
```

this will destroy person sections before person destroying.

looks like you need:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :sections, dependent: :nullify
```